# Streamlit unzipp file

Tags: python, deployment, zip, streamlit

I want to deploy my ML model using streamlit but streamlit can only allow users upload a file at a time. As a result I am trying to allow user upload a zip file containing images so that the images can be extracted at the backed end and use for prediction. Anytime I test the below code, it keeps throwing:

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'seek'.

How can I solve this.

```
import altair as alt
import streamlit as st
from PIL import Image
from pathlib import Path
import base64
import io
import pandas as pd
import zipfile
import filetype

st.set_page_config(page_title='Br Classifier', page_icon = 'nm.jpg', layout = 'wide', 
initial_sidebar_state = 'expanded')

image = Image.open(r"C:\Users\taiwo\Desktop\image.jfif")
st.image(image, use_column_width=True)

st.write("""
#CLASSIFICATION

This application helps to classify different classes

***
""")

# pylint: enable=line-too-long
from typing import Dict

import streamlit as st


@st.cache(allow_output_mutation=True)
def get_static_store() -> Dict:
   """This dictionary is initialized once and can be used to store the files uploaded"""
   return {}


def main():
   """Run this function to run the app"""
   static_store = get_static_store()

   st.info(__doc__)
   file_uploaded = st.file_uploader("Upload", type=["png","jpg","jpeg", "zip"], 
   accept_multiple_files=True,)
   with zipfile.ZipFile(file_uploaded,"r") as z:
        z.extractall(".")
            
            
   selected_model = st.sidebar.selectbox(
   'Pick an image classifier model',
   ('CNN_CLASSIFIER', 'Neural Network'))

   st.write('You selected:', selected_model)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this part of your code:

```
file_uploaded = st.file_uploader("Upload", type=["png","jpg","jpeg", "zip"], 
                                  accept_multiple_files=True,)
with zipfile.ZipFile(file_uploaded,"r") as z:
    z.extractall(".")
```

`file_uploaded` return a `list` and with `with` part you're trying to read the entire list and not the file itself.

Using a `for` loop can fix this error.

```
file_uploaded = st.file_uploader("Upload", type=["png","jpg","jpeg", "zip"], 
                                  accept_multiple_files=True,)
# iterate over each file uploaded
for file in file_uploaded:
    if file is not None:
        if file.endswith(".zip"):
            with zipfile.ZipFile(file_uploaded,"r") as z:
                z.extractall(".")
        else:
            # the part of your code which deals with img extensions
```

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/13932099/rafael-colombo, Thanks for your answer. However, I am still getting an error:
 `AttributeError: 'UploadedFile' object has no attribute 'endswith'
Traceback:
File "C:\Users\taiwo.osunrinde\Anaconda3\envs\st\lib\site-packages\streamlit\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 557, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "breccia_rock.py", line 66, in <module>
    main()
File "breccia_rock.py", line 50, in main
    if file.endswith(".zip"):`